# Does this sentences make sense?

Tags: grammar

Context:
Hey look! The Golden Gate Bridge! Isn’t that great?! It’s not made out of solid gold like we thought, which is kind of a disappointment, but still! 
Does this sentences make sense ?

> It's not like we think.
>
> It's not like we thought.

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong? Is this homework by any chance? You should tell  us first.

Comment: In my head, I insert a "had" in front of thought or place change we to "we'd", but it sounds fine to me.

Comment: Interestingly, in a different context, `It's not like we think` is also a correct sentence, but has a different meaning - the group would be berating themselves for making a silly decision, possibly involving sarcasm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It's not like we thought.

Is correct.

*Thought*, used here, is the past tense of *think*.

Since we have now seen the bridge ourselves we *no longer think* that it is made of gold. But, in the past, we *thought* it was.