# Can I say a sentence make sense? And How do I say its comparative degree?

Tags: phrase-usage

When I ask the question I find this
[Does this sentences make sense?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/150963/does-this-sentences-make-sense)

So, I think we can say a sentence make sense. Then how do we say more "make sense"?

For example, there are 2 sentences about "with concerns".

> Racism against Asians is becoming more entrenched in Canada, **with
> concerns** perhaps the sharpest in British Columbia, the country’s
> westernmost province known for its diverse Asian communities.

> It targets digital users **with concerns** about unexpected death.

I feel the sencond one is more "make sense" than the first one for using of "with concers".

Comment: "I feel the second one makes more sense". (I'm not sure that it does - it just uses _with concerns_ in a different way.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It targets digital users with concerns about unexpected death.

This clause does not seem to be related to its preceding one, on racism.

We leave that aside and focus on your main question.

*make sense* is defined in [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/make-sense) as

> to be clear and easy to understand

> This last paragraph doesn’t make any sense.

As shown in the example from the dictionary, to vary the degree of this phrase, we could insert *any* or *more*, etc.

You could say

> I feel the second one "makes more sense" than the first on the use of "with concern".

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you'd be ungrammatical. In your example, "does" is a helping verb, so "make" is in the infinitive form, the to-less infinitive form. It may not seem like "does" is a helping verb because the sentence is a question, so the sentence structure is inverted. Let's uninvert it and you can more easily see:

> This sentence does make sense.

See how "does" is the helping verb before "make"? Since you'd ***never*** conjugate both verbs, you'd ***never*** say:

> This sentence does makes sense.

Consequently, when you invert the structure to turn that statement into a question, you'd say:

> Does this sentence make sense?

You would ***never*** say:

> Does this sentence makes sense?